# Remove from Cart is not Working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is my code

```
     $scope.cart = [];

        $scope.addToCart = function (cat) {
        var found = false;
        $scope.cart.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.id === cat.product_id) {
                item.quantity++;
                found = true;
            }
        });
        if (!found) {
            $scope.cart.push(angular.extend({quantity: 1}, cat));

        }
    };

//remove from cart function 
        $scope.removeToCart = function (cat) {
            console.log(cat.product_id);
            var found = false;
            $scope.cart.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.id === cat.product_id) {
                    item.quantity--;
                    found = true;
                }
            });
            if (!found) {
                $scope.cart.push(angular.extend({quantity: 1}, cat));



        }
    };

    console.log($scope.cart);

        $scope.getCartPrice = function () {
            var total = 0;

            $scope.cart.forEach(function (cat) {
                total += cat.finalprice * cat.quantity;
            });
            return total;
        };
```

Comment: Can you be a more elaborate with what you are passing in "cat"? If it is an object can you share details of that please? Questions looks bit unclear right now. Also can you show how remove function is being called?

Comment: i ma passing product_id in cat, no that's not a object <a class="ion-ios-minus-outline minus" ng-click="removeToCart(cat);"></a>
                 <label id="{{cat.product_id}}" >0</label>
                <a class="ion-ios-plus-outline plus" ng-click="addToCart(cat);"></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to remove this bit from your removeToCart function:

```
if (!found) {
   $scope.cart.push(angular.extend({quantity: 1}, cat));
}
```

If "cat" is not found in the cart, you'll always add one with quantity of 1. Both "addToCart" and "removeToCart" seems identical for me, apart the item.quantity++ and item.quantity-- lines.